# File Upload in Web not working

Tags: php

i have working codes from my server which is really working using Xampp server but when i uploaded it to my hosting site, it seems the whole uploading isn't working.. what is missing? the temp folder? do i need to make a temp folder to my hosting site?

Comment: Well unless you tell us what errors you're getting anything we say is purely speculation. Help us so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure for:

- Upload limits on the server, php.ini
- Folder permissions, chmod to 755
- You are specifying the correct path
- You have used the `enctype` in `form` attribute
- Turn on error reporting in case it is off

**Update:**

The `enctype` should be set to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` eg:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And you can turn on error reporting by putting these lines on top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_erros', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Additionally try to see what does `$_FILES` array contain after form is submitted:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: File Uploads file_uploads Whether to allow HTTP file uploads = On
,
Folder permissions, chmod to from 755 to 777

You have used the enctype in form attribute what should i use sir?

and how to turn on the error reporting? :)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have not settup the permission for your upload path.
Check the permission for upload path. 
First try by making the permission to world write format (777).

Comment: Always make error_reporting(E_ALL) when development time. So you can track what is going on.

Comment: [error_reporting()](http://php.net/error-reporting) is a function. Make sure it's the first line in your code, so you don't miss any errors.

Comment: Yea add that in the start of any line of your code. If you are using session, then put under session_start();
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_reporting.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check two things :

- The folder where file gets uploaded
  exist on server or not ?
- Write permissions on that folder